# Request object of python urllib module

Tags: python-3.x

Why do we need to create a requests object for an url when we can directly fetch the url using urllib.request.urlopen() ?

Comment: can support your argument using an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP is based on requests and responses - the client makes requests and servers send responses. urllib.request mirrors this with a Request object which represents the HTTP request you are making. In its simplest form you create a Request object that specifies the URL you want to fetch. Calling urlopen with this Request object returns a response object for the URL requested. This response is a file-like object, which means you can for example call .read() on the response

Comment: There are also examples where urlopen is used directly to fetch the URL . So, what's the difference between the two methods?

Comment: Please go through this link http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/how-to-use-urllib2-in-python/